# SQL: Use calculated column just defined in subsequent calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

The title looks a little bit bulky, but I don't know any better words to phase, what I want to achieve. It's a pretty simple question: If I define a column in my SQL query with the `AS` keywords, can I immediately access this column from the next column?

```
SELECT
  LEAD(StoredOn) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_ChargeCarrier ORDER BY StoredOn) AS LeftOn,
  LeftOn - StoredOn AS TimeDifference
FROM MyTable
```

This one, quite obviously, doesn't work. I know, that I could make it work by replacing the `LeftOn` in the second column definition with the exact same `LEAD` function. But does that harm the performance, or does SQL server understand, that the two calls are redundand?

Comment: use a `CTE` or `derived table`

Comment: @Squirrel What is a `CTE`? I've never heard that term.

Comment: `Common Table Expression` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `subquery`

```
select t1.LeftOn, t1.LeftOn  - t1.StoredOn  AS TimeDifference from
(SELECT
  LEAD(StoredOn) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_ChargeCarrier ORDER BY StoredOn) AS LeftOn,
  StoredOn
FROM MyTable) t1
```

Comment: Would that bring any performance benefins in comparison to just duplicate the `LEAD` call?

Comment: well, you will have 2 separate computations,

Comment: I've tested your idea in a benchmark against Tim Biegeleisen's solution, and they have the exact same runtime. They create a slightly different execution plan, though.

Answer (score 2):

**Use CTE Function** i.e. Common Table Expression

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT LEAD(StoredOn) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_ChargeCarrier ORDER BY StoredOn) AS LeftOn,ID_ChargeCarrier AS CTEId FROM MyTable
)

SELECT   LeftOn - a.StoredOn AS TimeDifference
FROM MyTable a INNER JOIN CTE b
ON a.ID_ChargeCarrier = b.CTEId
```

Comment: In comparison to Tim Biegeleisen's solution, which one would be preferable?

Comment: why are you joining back the same table again when you can just expose the `StoredOn` column in the `CTE`

Comment: I made some tests with three views with three different methods (unmodified, double `LEAD` and `CTE`) and the `CTE` version was the slowest

Answer (score 2):

If you want performance, you would just repeat the `LEAD` here:

```
SELECT
  LEAD(StoredOn) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_ChargeCarrier ORDER BY StoredOn) AS LeftOn,
  LEAD(StoredOn) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_ChargeCarrier ORDER BY StoredOn) - StoredOn AS TimeDifference
FROM MyTable;
```

It is true that this does not look nice, but it avoids a subquery, which means that the above query could fully run using indices, should they exist and be usable.

Comment: In comparison to akhilesh singh's solution, which one would be preferable?

Comment: @AndréReichelt You should benchmark both versions, and see which is faster.  If both performances are roughly the same, then maybe go with the other answers, which are a bit less verbose than mine.

Comment: It seems, that it doesn't introduce any additional cost. The duplication of `LEAD` introduces a new hop in the execution plan, but with a cost of 0. It seems, that SQL server optimizes the second, identical call away.

Comment: This is what I would expect more or less.  Doing the additional subquery is probably a bigger penalty versus the savings of calling `LEAD` twice.

Comment: SQL Server will most likely treat the three queries as identical. If in doubt you can compare their plans. They should be same.

Comment: I have checked, cte and subselect are the same, but double LEAD() is worst in terms of cost but could be better in terms of execution time, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have done some tests and found that performances of the different solutions are affected by number of records involved, so different scenarios can be presented.

`CTE` and `SUBSELECT` are really almost the same, also same plan.. 
`Double LEAD()` should be always the worst, looking the plan seems that the `LEAD()` is calculated two times (with a segment and a sequence project) with a cost greater than the scalar value of cte and subselect.
But, it seems that `Double LEAD()` can take better advantage of parallelism, so total time of execution could be lower.

For huge table with very much rows `Double LEAD()` is probably the worst option, while `CTE` or `SUBSELECT` will be the best.

There is another option, you can use a `CTE` with `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `LEAD()`.
The query plan is really ugly compared to the others, but the execution time could be better than ohter solutions, it depends on SQL Server version (Express or Standard) and on Server Hardware (cores and ram) for parallelism.

Check something like that:

```
;WITH
l AS (
    SELECT ID_ChargeCarrier, StoredOn, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_ChargeCarrier ORDER BY StoredOn) AS row_id
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT 
    ID_ChargeCarrier, l1.StoredOn, l2.StoredOn AS LeftOn,  
    l2.StoredOn, l1.StoredOn AS TimeDifference
FROM l l1
LEFT JOIN l l2 ON l1.ID_ChargeCarrier = l2.ID_ChargeCarrier AND l1.n = l2.n - 1
```

For my tests I use this table, populated with 3 millions record.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_Memberships](
    [MembershipId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ValidFromDateKey] [date] NOT NULL,
    [ValidToDateKey] [date] NULL,
    [ColInt] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ColGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ColVarChar] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [ColChk]  AS (checksum([ColVarChar])),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Memberships] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MembershipId] ASC) 
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[_Memberships] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Memberships_ColGUID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [ColGUID]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_checksum] ON [dbo].[_Memberships]([ColChk] ASC)
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I know that this solution is not the best one, but I would point out that even such a (bad) solution could be a solution in particular circumstances.

I think that the main difference could be in the SQL Version and in the hardware of the server. If you have not Express edition and you have many cores, things can change quickly.

Pay also attention to how quick the data changes in your table and if your query is always  the same or if it is parametrized.

Caching can have a role..

Comment: You might want to also add the details of the data set you used to conclude your benchmarks (e.g. size, cardinality, etc.).

Comment: That's pretty interesting. On our production database, CTE was *by far* the worst performing option. Also, the CTE preselect can't be optimized away, even if you don't need the calculated columns in your request.